# Bash - Remove specific character from variable words

Tags: regex, bash, variables

I write a text file in which I describe parameters as follow :

```
status.u16OK=0x00
status.u16NOK=0x01
status.u16NOTDEFINED=0x02
```

The following function must returns the status.

```
function identifyStatus()
{
    while read lines                    
    do  
        input=${lines%=*}               
        firstTerm=${input%.*}           
        ID=${lines##*=}

        if [ $firstTerm == "status" ] && [ $((ID)) == $2 ];then
            secondTerm=${input#*.} 
            echo "status : $secondTerm"
        fi
    done < $1
}
```

I would like to retrieve status : OK instead of status : u16OK

Answer (score 2):

You may think to use IFS to simplify the code.

```
$IFS - internal field separator
```

Here is the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

IFS=".="
while read status id value x
do
  if [ "$status" == "status" ] && [ "$value" == $2 ];then
      echo "Status ${id:3}"
  fi
done < $1
```

Comment: Thank ! This is quite powerful. What is the aim of the line IFS=".=" ? Because IFS is not used

Answer (score 1):

You can use `${string:position}` to extracts substring from `$string` at `$position`

```
~$ secondTerm="u16NOTDEFINED"
~$ echo ${secondTerm:3}
NOTDEFINED
```

You could also specify a length with `${string:position}`:

```
~$ input="status.u16NOTDEFINED"
~$ echo ${input:7:3}
u16
```

Comment: Thank a lot ! It is similar to a cut ?

Answer (score 0):

Modify the line:

```
secondTerm=${input#*.}
```

to:

```
secondTerm=${input#*.u16}
```

:)